# Multi language blog with Nuxt3 and Firebase

Tags: firebase, nuxt.js, nuxt3

At the moment I have a one language blog website using Nuxt3 and Firebase.

I am getting my post the following way:

```
<script setup>
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router'
import { doc, updateDoc } from '@firebase/firestore'
import { useDocument, useFirestore } from 'vuefire'

const db = useFirestore()
const route = useRoute()
const docRef = doc(db, 'posts', route.params.id)

const post = useDocument(docRef)
</script>
```

The database design is simple - I have a `body` and a `title` for each blog post.

I have read the documentation of nuxt i18n module and I know how to make the static translation of the website, my question is how to design the database and show the dynamic translation?

For example: If the route has `en` parameter to show the `en title` and if it has `es` parameter to show the `es title`? What is the best way to store the information in Firebase and the best way to retrieve it?